# App State Preservation and Restoration, whille going to background state the app is restarting

Tags: react-native

**State preservation while come back to app**

1. when i go to background or inactive or in home the app is reloading  and starting from the intial screen.
2. and also when i redirect to another app from my app and when i come back it start from initial screen, please help me with this.

I want state persistence when switching to another app or going home, when I return, the app should start from where it was.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.